# Probability that two drawn cards values are the same after an interchange

Tags: probability

> Shuffle a full deck of cards and divide it into two stacks of $26$
> cards.  A card is taken from the top of the first stack, and, after
> its value is observed, put into the second stack. The second stack is
> then reshuffled, a card is dealt from the top, and its value observed.
>
> What is the probability that the two values are the same?

The solution in my text is a follows:

Let $I$ denote the event that the interchanged card is selected.
Let $S$ be the event that the two values are the same.
Then
$$P(S)=P(I)P(S|I)+P(I^c)P(S|I^c)=\frac{1}{27}\cdot 1+\frac{26}{27}\frac{3}{51}.$$

I came to the same conclusion in my own work, except for the $3/51$.

Why is $P(S|I^c)=3/51$ as opposed to $1/51$?

Comment: When you say "value" do you mean, say, that drawing $3\clubsuit$ and then $3\diamondsuit$ is a success?

Comment: Yes, value here refers to the rank of the cards.

Comment: Well, then there are $\frac 3{51}$ choices that match value without being the same card.  How do you get $\frac 1{51}$?

Comment: I see my mistake now. For some reason I was assuming there was only one card with matching rank.